# Cancelling MouseEvent.CLICK after MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN

Tags: actionscript-3, events, stoppropagation

I have a MOUSE_DOWN handler that creates a CLICK event listener on a child object. Naturally, as soon as you release the mouse button, if you happen to be over the child object, the CLICK event fires.

I was disappointed to discover that event.stopImmediatePropagation doesn't interrupt the CLICK event from registering the MOUSE_DOWN as part of its detection cycle. It makes sense that it doesn't but still... disappointing.

A MouseEvent.CLICK consists of detecting a MOUSE_DOWN on the object and then if it's followed by a MOUSE_UP without leaving the object, he event fires. I had hoped that by cancelling the MOUSE_DOWN event, it would clear that out of the CLICK buffer, but no such potatoes, alas.

Any tricks out there? This could all be handled with a flag and a couple more MOUSE_UP and MOUSE_DOWN handlers, but dang, smacks of effort... Buehler?

Comment: add the click event on mouse up not mouse down.

Comment: Have you tried capturing the CLICK in the container and stopping its propagation based on a simple flag that one could trigger in the DOWN event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you *should* be able to correct this behavior in the following way:

Instead of a MOUSE_DOWN handler, have a CLICK handler.

That CLICK handler will remove the listener associated with it, and create a *new* CLICK listener with a reference to the function you want to be the new CLICK handler.

IE:

```
//on CreationComplete, or wherever you are adding the MOUSE_DOWN listener
addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handler1);

private function handler1(aEvent:MouseEvent):void
{
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handler1);
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handler2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sam. This solution is the same as the workaround I'm currently using. However, there's a difference in functionality. From a UX perspective, the desired effect is to have a distinct event happen on mouse down, and another on a subsequent release (but NOT the same gesture as the mouse down). In other words you're looking for a mouse down - something happens; mouse up - nothing happens; click on child element - something else happens.

Comment: @Tom, Well, you could put an onCapture MOUSE_UP listener in place in the MOUSE_DOWN handler. You could then stop that event's propagation, and remove the listener inside the MOUSE_UP handler. That *should* do what you're looking for.

Comment: Assuming that halting the MOUSE_UP before it hits the target stage will prevent the CLICK.

Comment: yeah I wonder whether the runtime engine sees those as two distinct types of events, or two aspects of the same event. probably the former would be my guess.

Answer (score 0):

stopping the propagation of an event only stops the event from flowing thru the display list, it doesn't reverse time and cancel or deregister the event.

[ActionScript 3.0:  The Event Flow](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e4f.html)

if you want to cancel an event just remove the event listener.

Comment: Removing the event listener doesn't cancel the event in progress.